# Reactjs fetch making endless calls to api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch data from the server using react fetch function, but it's making endless calls to the API

I am returning an array from the API, which only needs a single API call but fetch() makes infinite calls regardless of the endpoint.

```
    function Posts(){
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [data, setData] = useState({posts : [{
    title : ''
  }]});

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
.then( res => res.json())
.then( data => {
    setData({posts: data})
})

  return(
    <Container className={classes.container}>

    </Container>
  )
}
```

I expect it to make only single or two calls so that it doesn't spam the server.

Comment: Where exactly did you put that call? In `componentDidMount()` like you're supposed to? Because if you put that in `render()` you'll get an infinite loop. `setState` causes a re-render, and thus cannot be inside `render()`. You should have a warning alluding to this in your browser console.

Comment: Exactly as suggested by @ChrisG. Post the full code. You must have a **maximum update depth exceeded** error in your console.

Comment: @ChrisG, I'm also new to React, so just asking, does setData internally do a setState?

Comment: In the OP case I guess? `setData` is not an official React function.

Comment: Nobody can guess why until you provide a [mcve]. Showing us only a simple `fetch()` will not create the symptoms described on it's own

Comment: @ChrisG I think its because I have put it about the return fn, I am not using class component I am using functional components and put it inside the same function where the rendering components are.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt Hi, using useState() to assing values.

Comment: You're doing `fetch()` again every time the function is called, and the function is called when you do `setData()` which leads to the infinite loop. You have to use [effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for anything that changes the state like Ajax calls.

Comment: Here's the [FAQ entry](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-do-data-fetching-with-hooks). It links to [this article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/) which gives a good in-depth explanation. In short, move the the `fetch()` call to `useEffects()` and pass `[]` as second argument to prevent the loop: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-cohen-2c0iy

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I resolved it with useEffect() only

Comment: Right, so this is a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55484033/reactjs-how-to-call-useeffect-hook-only-once-to-fetch-api-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
```

wrapping fetch inside `useEffect()` solved the issue,

```
function Posts(){
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [data, setData] = useState({posts : [{
    title : ''
  }]});


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then( res => res.json())
    .then( data => {
        setData({posts: data})
    })
  }, []);
```

`useEffect()` only after the render, we can also choose to run it if any value changes.

Answer (score 3):

To ensure that only a single API call is made, call the fetch function inside `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method of your component.

`componentDidMount()` method is called after the component is mounted into the DOM and it is called only once in a component's lifecycle.
You can also then use `setState()` method to set the received data into your state.

Check below code,

```
class A extends Component{
   componentDidMount() {
     fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
     .then( res => res.json())
     .then( data => {
        this.setState({posts: data})
     })
   }

   render() {
    // your code
   }
}
```

Note: Calling `setState()` inside `render()` method can cause the component to re-render and hence executing in infinite loop.

If you are using functional component then `useEffect()` can be used to fetch the data only once when the component is mounted. Check [ReactJS: how to call useEffect hook only once to fetch API data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55484033/reactjs-how-to-call-useeffect-hook-only-once-to-fetch-api-data/56302378#56302378)

Comment: while this works fine, I was actually not using class-based components.

Comment: There is another way to call the API only once, using useEffect() react hook of functional components. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55484033/reactjs-how-to-call-useeffect-hook-only-once-to-fetch-api-data/56302378#56302378, I have answered with an example. @Udit