# How to update path on component mount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I have a login/signup form in one component and I'm trying to update the URL path accordingly. But I have a few issues I'm trying to address. **I am using Firebase fetchSignInMethodsForEmail() to check if user exists if it's an empty array it is a new user.**

1. when prop `new` is true. It will render the create password input and update URL from /login to /signup. Ideal output: https://id.atlassian.com/login type any random email address. url changes from login -> signup and create password input mount.

The current output is that /signup will only trigger(display) if and only if I clicked Form.Item which is wrapped with `<Link to="/signup">...</>`

2. If I directly type path /signup how can I trigger redux to dispatch an action that will update `new`

I tried using useRouteMatch to get path and if it equals /signup then dispatch an action to toggle `new` but by doing this I'm getting too many re-renders error

```
if(match.path === "/signup")
{
     dispatch(new());
}
```

**Current Route:**

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/signup" component={Login} />
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
</Switch>
```

**Login.js**

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { new } = useSelector(
    state => state.auth
  ); 
  const match = useRouteMatch();
  if(match.path === "/signup)
  {
     dispatch(new());
  }

  return (
    <Form>
        Email
      <Form.Item>
          <Input placeholder="Username" />
      </Form.Item>

        {new ? (
          <div>
          <Link to="/signup">
            Create password
            <Form.Item>
                <Input.Password placeholder="Password"/>
            </Form.Item>
           </Link>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            Enter your password
            <Form.Item>
                <Input.Password placeholder="Password"/>
            </Form.Item>
          </div>
      )}
      </Link>
      {new ? (
        <Button>
          Sign up
        </Button>
      ) : (
        <Button>
          Log in
        </Button>
      )}
    </Form>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to dispatch this action once, after the mounting phase of your component. In that case, the [`useEffect()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook might be a good fit:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

...

const match = useRouteMatch();

const onMount = () => {
  /* This callback is invoked after mount */
  if(match.path === "/signup)
  {
     dispatch(new());
  }
}

/* The effect hook runs the following callback as a side effect */
useEffect(() => {
  onMount();
}, []); /* Empty array causes the effect to only run once (on mount) */
```

For more information on why the empty array causes the effect callback to trigger once, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55484033/reactjs-how-to-call-useeffect-hook-only-once-to-fetch-api-data).

Also, a small suggestion - consider renaming the `new()` function and `new` variable to something else (perhaps `New`?), seeing that `new` is a reserved keyword.

Hope that helps!

### Update

You could take the following "non-redux" approach that achieves the login/sign up flow that's similar to the link your provided:

```
const { useState } from "react";

const AuthForm = () => {

  /* Define state shape */
  const [state, setState] = useState({ 
    username : "", 
    password : "", 
    isNew : false 
  });

  /* Field update helpers */
  const setUsername = (username) => setState(s => ({ ...s, username }))
  const setPassword = (password) => setState(s => ({ ...s, password }))

  const login = async () => {
    const { username, password } = state;
    /* login logic */
  }

  const signup = async () => {
    const { username, password } = state;
    /* signup logic */
  }

  const checkUsername = async () => {

    /*
    const response = await fetch("/api/check-username-exists", { 
        method : "POST", 
        body : JSON.stringify({ userNameToCheck : state.username })
    })

    // say that response.found is true when user name we checked 
    // does exist in database
    setState(s => ({ ...s, isNew : !response.found }));
    */
  }

  const renderFields = () => {

    if(!username) {
      return <>
        <Form.Item>
          <Input placeholder="Username" 
                 onChange={e =>setUsername(e.target.value)} />
        </Form.Item>
        <Button onClick={checkUsername}>
          Continue
        </Button>
      </>
    }
    else {
      return <>
      <p>Login as { state.username }</p>
      {
        state.isNew ? (<div>
          <p>Create password</p>
          <Form.Item>
            <Input.Password placeholder="Password"
                onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
          </Form.Item>
          <Button onClick={signup}>
            Sign up
          </Button>
        </div>) : (<div>
          <p>Enter your password</p>
          <Form.Item>
            <Input.Password placeholder="Password" 
                 onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
          </Form.Item>
          <Button onClick={login}>
            Log in
          </Button>
        </div>)
      }
      </>
    }
  }

  return (<Form>{renderFields()}</Form>);
}
```

Please keep in mind that this is just skeleton code intended to illustrate a "non-redux" way of implementing the form. It will need to be completed with appropriate calls to your backend/API, etc however hopefully this gives you some ideas on how to achieve what your require :-)

Comment: Yes it is different in my code. This should solve 2. Do you have any idea how I can overcome issue 1? Also React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'dispatch' and 'match.path'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. How do I surpress this?

Comment: Just updated code to resolve that warning - not quite sure I understand the first point sorry? You're wanting the password form item to show after the user clicks on the sign up button - is that correct?

Comment: The first instance will show Username input and Login button with URL /login. When I enter a username (in the username input) and is not found NEW will become true. This will display create password input and signup button and change URL to /signup. Hope that is easier to understand. Also, the warning has not been resolved. It's not a big issue since but would be nice to surpress.

Comment: You might find it easier to manage this directly in your component (ie without redux/dispatch/etc). You could `useState` locally to determine if a user exists for the user name provided and then update `New` as local component state to control rendering of the signup/login form items

Comment: I think my issue is that when new = true then on component mount I want the URL to change /login to /signup. What I currently have is /signup URL is only applied when I physically have to click on anywhere within Form.Item.

Comment: Please see example. https://id.atlassian.com/login type any email. Url updates to login -> signup and create password is mounted.

Comment: @Freddy. sorry for the delay getting back to you - just updated the answer with some code suggesting a non-redux approach. Does that help?

Comment: I think with your updated code it will function the same as what I have but the issue I'm having is that when state.isNew = true in this scenario url will stay as  /login however I am looking for the **URL to change to /signup when isNew = true**

Comment: The code snippet I posted above is currently my only route. I can load components just fine and I think the only thing I need would be to change url from /login to signup when Create password mounts.

Comment: I can get it as far as wrapping Form.Item with <Link to="/signup"> but input needs to be clicked for url to change.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the local state to control rather than redux store?

```
const [isNew, setIsNew] = useState(location && location.pathname === '/signup')

function handleEmailCheck(event) {
  // use Firebase fetchSignInMethodsForEmail() to check the email
  // and use setIsNew() & history.pushState() to update address bar render content
}

return (
  <Form>
      Email
    <Form.Item>
        <Input placeholder="Username" onBlur={handleEmailCheck} />
    </Form.Item>
    ...
```