# A mistake in React + REST API

Tags: reactjs, api, rest

My **API config:**

```
// Get all characters
const getAllCharacters = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(API_URL + "/character");
    return await response.json();
};
```

**API URL:**

```
const API_URL = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api";

export { API_URL };
```

**My Home.jsx:**

```
// API
import { getAllCharacters } from "../api";

//Function

function Home() {
    const [character, setCharacter] = useState([]);
    // API
    useEffect(() => {
        getAllCharacters()
            .then((data) => {
                setCharacter(data.results);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, [character]);
    return <div>name: {character.name}</div>;
}
```

Result:
`name:`

There is my component:

[image: Text]

I cant understand why this is not working (Im newbie in React JS, so dont judge me please)

P.S. `{character[0].name}` throw an error: `TypeError: can't access property "name", character[0] is undefined`

Comment: The result is an array.. which is why you are not able to see it. character[0].name will show the first item for you

Comment: TypeError: can't access property "name", character[0] is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As stated in the comment, you're getting an array, so you'll need something like `map()` to loop over them
- Also, to call the API just once, you'll need to add an empty array to the `useEffect` instead of the `character` variable, that will cause infinity calls.

  <sup>More info about this: [ReactJS: how to call useEffect hook only once to fetch API data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55484033/reactjs-how-to-call-useeffect-hook-only-once-to-fetch-api-data)</sup>

Applying those fixed gives us something like this:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [character, setCharacter] = useState([]);
    
    const API_URL = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api";
    
    const getAllCharacters = () => {
        return fetch(API_URL + "/character")
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(json => json);
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getAllCharacters()
            .then((data) => {
                setCharacter(data.results);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, [ ]);
    
    return (
        <div>
            {character.map(c => {
                return <span>{c.name}</span>;
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
div { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just need to .map
`<div>{character.map((character) => (<div>{character.name}</div>))}</div>`